# Visual Studio emulator failed to Start due to Server execution failure

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator

I have tried the following for the past four days

1. Repaired Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android
2. Repaired Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators
3. Removed of all existing virtual Switches
4. Ran XdeClenup.exe
5. Disabled Network Sharing on Ethernet

No luck yet. i still get error that;

The emulator was unable to verify that Virtual machine is running.(checked my vmms service and its on and running)

Something happened while starting a virtual machine 'VS Emulator 5" Inch Kit Kat(4.4) XXHDPI Phone' virtual Machine ID(.......)

'VS Emulator 5" Inch Kit Kat(4.4) XXHDPI Phone' failed to start worker process: Server Execution failed (0x80080005). Virtual Machine ID (........) [Error message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIuyo.png)

My Ram size is 4gb, OS is Windows 8.1 Pro

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's your RAM capacity

Comment: I have 4gb of RAM. My OS is Windows 8.1 pro

Answer (score 0):

VS Android required 8gb of RAM .. try Xamarin emulator for Android , install Xamarin Android emulator check it out here
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/quick-start-tutorial-manual-or-quick-way-of-xamarin-and-simulator-installation/

Comment: Thanks, Never knew about the RAM limitation. But I installed xamarin Android Player as an alternative was still having issues. The emulator shuts down without any error message after displaying a loading progress bar for a while. I have all the necessary files installed as well as the latest Xamarin Studio.

Comment: Initally I had also same problem , Disable hyper v in BIOS and is working